# eclipse XML editor / Java Editor: javadoc and links for packages, methods and files

Tags: xml, eclipse, javadoc, properties-file

How should we specify external files in Javadoc and is there a way to show/link these entries in the XML-editor, too?

This is what I have so far:

- Java:

  - JavaDoc shown (via [mouse hover]) in declaration of package, class, method
  - link (via [CTRL]) in the editor for the referenced class and method
  - usable link in the JavaDoc popup editor to show Javadoc for the referenced package, class, method
  - working "external" link only for non-Java file with `@see`

[image: possible Java-Doc in Java editor]

- XML

  - a kind of JavaDoc shown (via [mouse hover]) only for the class
  - link (via [CTRL]) in the editor for the class and for the files specified with the full-name (TestProperties.properties, TestXML.xml)

[image: possible "Java-Doc" in XML editor]

TestClass.java:

```java
package org.test;

/**
 * JavaDoc for TestClass, referencings some stuff:<br />
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link org.test.TestClass#testMethod}</li>
 * <li>{@link org.test.TestClass}</li>
 * <li>{@link org.test}</li>
 * <li>{@link resources#TestXML}<br/>
 * --> every other way of writing leads to "cannot be resolved to a type"</li>
 * <li>{@link resources#TestProp}</li>
 * <li>{@link resources#TestNotThere}</li>
 * <li>direct link without annotation: <a href="../../resources/TestProp.properties">property again </a></li>
 * </ul>
 * @see <a href="../../resources/TestProp.properties">property link</a>
 */
public class TestClass {

  /** JavaDoc for testMethod */
  public void testMethod() {
    // some method implementation
  }
}
```

Sample layout in the source folder:

```
org.test
->package-info.java
->TestClass.java
resources
->TestProp.properties
->TestXML.xml
```

TestXML.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testroot>
  <testmethod name="org.test.TestClass#testMethod" />
  <testclass name="org.test.TestClass" />
  <testpackage name="org.test" />
  <testproperty name="resources#TestProp" />
  <testproperty name="TestProp" />
  <testproperty name="TestProp.properties" />
  <testxml name="resources#TestXML" />
  <testxml name="TestXML" />
  <testxml name="TestXML.xml" />
</testroot>
```

Questions:

- Is there a better/correct way to specify non-java files in JavaDoc?
- Is there a better/correct way to specify method names in XML and/or a different XML editor to use within Eclipse?

Comment: `<a href="...">` links work perfectly outside of an `@see` section. Is there any restriction that prevents you from using them?

Comment: @Lolo I've fixed the link use (both "outside" of `@see` and with a correct `@see`) in the answer. The unwanted part of the link is that it is opened outside the IDE - is there an option to reference it so that it would be opened in a new tab instead and that *any* link is usable in the XML editor [which just shows its text]?